# What it means by Modulo $1$ in a self-transformation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, transformation

Could anyone tell me what this transformation looks like?

$T: [0,1)\to [0,1), T(x)= 10x\quad (\text{mod} \quad 1)$

If $x=0.31$ then $T(x)=3.1$, now modulo $1$ means what? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a way of saying "Take the decimal part". Clearly multiplying by $10$ easily brings you out of the interval $[0,1)$, so this solves the problem.
In this way $T(0.31)=0.1$.

A correct way of writing that should be:
$$T(x)=10x-\lfloor 10x \rfloor \ .$$
In your case you would have: $T(0.31) = 3.1-3=0.1$ .

Comment: Hi Thanks but do you have a definition for $\lfloor 10x \rfloor \ $? For any $x$ please? I am going to speak towards a general audience most of them does not have a Mathematics background at all.

Comment: @Myshkin if you talk to people without a mathematics background you can just tell them that your function multiplies a number by $10$ and then it just takes the decimal part. In my opinion this is the most simple way of telling that

Comment: @Randall modulo is defined for integers, the idea is clear but here modulo refers to modular arithmetic

Comment: @SilvioM Many Thanks!

Comment: @Randall Just look at the tags, it  says modulo arithmetic. It's not that modulo we are talking about. You clearly can define it in a thousands different ways

Comment: I have no idea about modulo $1$ on $\mathbb R$, would anyone shed some light on it?

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @Myshkin:  $\lfloor y \rfloor$ is the [greatest integer function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)